create a plugin in October CMS to upload images?
i am trying to make a plugin to upload images for a slider in october cms. The image is uploaded to public directory. But the path is not saved in databse. Also in backend the image is not showing(image:
label: Image
type: image
width: 100) . I want to store image in a custom path, also need to store/save path in databse.
model:
<?php namespace MyPlug\SliderTop\Models;

use Model;
use Storage; // For file storage handling

class SliderImage extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    // The name of the table to use
    public $table = 'myplug_slidertop_images';

    // The fillable attributes
    public $fillable = ['title', 'image'];

      // The field will be a file attachment
      public $attachOne = [
        'image' => ['System\Models\File']  // Define the relation for the 'image' field
    ];


    // Validation rules (optional)
    public $rules = [
        'image' => 'required|image'  // Ensures the uploaded file is an image
    ];

  
}

Controller:
<?php namespace MyPlug\SliderTop\Controllers;

use BackendMenu;
use Backend\Classes\Controller;
use Backend\Classes\WidgetManager;
use Osaka\SliderTop\Models\SliderImage;
use Flash;
use Input;
use Redirect;
use Validator;
use System\Models\File; // For managing file uploads

/**
 * Slider Images Controller Backend Controller
 */
class SliderImagesController extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [
        \Backend\Behaviors\FormController::class,
        \Backend\Behaviors\ListController::class,
    ];

    /**
     * @var string formConfig file
     */
    public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';

    /**
     * @var string listConfig file
     */
    public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';

    /**
     * @var array required permissions
     */
    public $requiredPermissions = ['myplug.slidertop.sliderimagescontroller'];

    /**
     * __construct the controller
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        BackendMenu::setContext('MyPlug.SliderTop', 'slidertop', 'sliderimagescontroller');
    }



}


# ===================================
#  List Column Definitions
# ===================================

columns:

    title:
        label: Title
        sortable: true
    description:
        label: Description
        sortable: true
    image:
        label: Image
        type: image
        width: 100


# ===================================
#  Form Field Definitions
# ===================================

fields:

    title:
        label: Title
        type: text
    description:
        label: Description
        type: textarea
    image:
        label: Image
        type: fileupload
        span: auto
        mode: image


path is not saved in database. or in backend list the image is not displaying...you say it's one or the other. But which is it, according to your debugging and testing? Or are you saying sometimes it's one and sometimes the other? If so can you see a pattern? The problem is unclear, from the way you've described it.

The problem is the image is uploading but path of the image not stored in databse. Also the image is not displaying in list (image:
label: Image
type: image
width: 100)

Ok. Well, the second thing is probably just a symptom of the first, I would expect. But please [edit] your question clarify the wording and the exact situation. Details are important.
